# How to print custom subsegments in the AWS X-Ray management console?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have added a main segment for routes for my REST API which is written in Node.js and runs on a Lambda function. I have also enabled API gateway tracing for X-Ray. I want to see sql query timing as a subsegment from X-Ray console so I have used AWSXRay.captureAsyncFunc function and added it for all sql queries and I am able to print tracing logs. The following screenshot shows a segment and a subsegment for a GET request.

[image: Logging X-Ray segment and subsegment]

I want to see the subsegment in the AWS X-Ray management console. In the tracing section of the X-Ray, I can only see API Gateway and Lambda timings.

[image: API Gateway and Lambda segments in the AWS X-Ray console]

Is anyone know how to print custom subsegments in the X-Ray timeline?

When I click on raw data from X-Ray console, this is what I see. I want to be able to see my custom segment. Raw data tab shows just segments of API Gateway and Lambda.

[image: Raw data tab]

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same problem.  I am using `.addNewSubsegment` and then `setSegment` but they do not appear in the raw json or the console.

Answer (score 2):

What is the Node runtime version of your Lambda function? Which type of lambda event handler are you using? Which version of X-Ray Node SDK are you using? What style/library you are using for calling your SQL database? Is it a callback, promise or async/await?

The reason your `getItem` subsegment not shown is probably that in your tracing logs the subsegment doesn't have `parent_id`. This is potentially an issue with the compatibility between Lambda node runtime and X-Ray SDK for Nodejs such that the SQL subsegment is not properly captured.

Please feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node with the answers to the above questions provided so workaround/fixes can be addressed.

Comment: Lambda Node version: 8.10

Comment: Lambda function is triggered by API Gateway service.
AWS-xray-sdk version 2.2.0 is used to add open/close Segment before and after express routes inside the app.
AWS-xray-sdk-core version 2.2.0 is used to call captureAsyncFunc.

I couldn't use aws-xray-sdk-postgres because I am using PoolClient instead of Client for postgres and aws-xray-sdk-postgres
 is expecting postgres Client object. So I had to use custom capture function.

Answer (score 1):

They are visible in the Raw Data tab in the console timeline view. That shows the exact same json as returned by BatchGetTraces API.

Comment: When I open raw data tab I cannot see my custom subsegment for sql queries. All I can see is the same as the timeline results. Some how my custom subsegment traces do not reach to the X-Ray Daemon. Although I am able to print my custom subsegment, I am unable to see it in the AWS X-Ray console.

Comment: Are you looking for the getItems subsegment? Is it missing for a particular trace or for all traces? A subsegment should not be orphan for it to be part of the trace. Looking at the trace you posted it does seem like it is part of a segment i.e. It is owned by a segment. So it does not seem like it is orphan. Also it should be well formed... It should at least have the required fields start, end time, name, id. Again getItems does not show any immediate problems

Comment: Yes I am looking for getItems subsegment. The trace I have posted it isn't from AWS X-Ray console. I have printed request logs whilst testing so the raw data is not the same and I can't find the same trace from the X-Ray console. I posted as an example of my custom subsegment from my logs. The problem is I can't see my custom subsegment from the X-Ray console.